# Pandas read_excel converting dates incorrectly

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have a large number of separate .xlsx files I am trying to compile into one master list. There are dates in two of the columns of data but they are in inconsistent formats, like 01/03/2021 and 01.03.2021, among other things. The data is so large I am not sure of all the different formats. I want all data in this new dataframe to just appear 1:1 with the original files so I can properly assess how to standardise all the data. Currently, it appears like any date with a leading 0 and separated by a / is converted into a date and timestamp like so:

```
01/11/2021 = 2021-01-11 00:00:00
```

This issue doesnt affect dates with dot seperations nor dates without the leading 0.

I am using this line of code to read each file into a dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, engine="openpyxl", skiprows=skip_rows, header=None, dtype=str, parse_dates=False)
```

As you can see, I have included the dtype=str arguments and parse_dates=False in an effort to stop these dates being converted, but it does not change anything. It is important that no data is lossed or changed from its original before I have a chance to verify correctness. How can I preserve the integrity of the original data?

Comment: convert that specific column into string while reading the excel file: ```df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, sheet, converters={'Date': str}```

Answer (score 0):

Your question requires a  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Anyways, the `parse_dates` will have no effect if your two columns are formatted as "[Date](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e)" in Excel (*see, [*GH47269*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/47269)*). We can read from the docs of [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) the following :

> `parse_dates` : *bool, list-like, or dict, default False*
>
> If a column or index contains an unparsable date, the entire column or
> index will be returned unaltered as an object data type. **If you don't
> want to parse some cells as date just change their type in Excel to
> "Text".** For non-standard datetime parsing, use pd.to_datetime after
> pd.read_excel.

I made an example to illustrate the general logic :

```
pd.read_excel("file.xlsx").pipe(lambda x: print(x, "-"*30, x.dtypes, sep="\n"))

  col1 (text) col2 (date)
0  03/01/2021  2021-01-03
1  11/01/2021  2021-01-11
------------------------------
col1 (text)            object
col2 (date)    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

---

When you pass `dtype=str`, you're roughly casting `datetime` objects to `str` :

```
from datetime import datetime

str(datetime(2021, 1, 11)) # '2021-01-11 00:00:00'

pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", dtype=str).pipe(lambda x: print(x, "-"*30, x.dtypes, sep="\n"))

  col1 (text)          col2 (date)
0  03/01/2021  2021-01-03 00:00:00
1  11/01/2021  2021-01-11 00:00:00
------------------------------
col1 (text)    object
col2 (date)    object
dtype: object
```

Used input (*file.xlsx*) :

[image]